# MySQL/PHP - text formatting

Tags: php, mysql, text

I've created a simple query to create a list of dates and descriptions from my calendar database.
The idea is that I have a PHP webpage that show a text list that I can quickly copy and paste into an email or text message.
My problem is that, although the text shows up correctly on the web page, when I paste the info into a text editor (Word, email, whatever) I'm getting tabs between each column.

How can I format the text in PHP so that it pastes correctly?

This is my code:-

```
if(mysql_num_rows($AvDates) > 0){
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
            while ($row_AvDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($AvDates)){ 
                ?>
                <li>
                    <?php echo htmlentities($row_AvDates['Month']);?>
                    <?php echo "-";?>
                    <?php echo htmlentities ($row_AvDates['the_days']);?>
                </li> 
                <?php
            }      
        ?>
     </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

This gives me output that looks correct, but pastes like this...

```
(Month[tab]"-"[tab] Dates)
```

How do I loose the tabs?

Comment: The tabs you're seeing are part of the HTML output since you're closing php tags and outputting HTML (with hidden tab chars). Echo out everything on one line or don't close the php tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing php and letting the HTML output be rendered. See tab chars below:

```
    [tab]<li><?php echo htmlentities($row_AvDates['Month']);?>
    [tab]<?php echo "-";?>
    [tab]<?php echo htmlentities ($row_AvDates['the_days']);?></li>
```

Solution:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($row_AvDates['Month']) . '-' . htmlentities ($row_AvDates['the_days']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Darren.

Try to use this code, it should solve your problem:

```
<?php if (mysql_num_rows($AvDates) > 0) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ($row_AvDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($AvDates)) : ?>
            <li><?php echo htmlentities($row_AvDates['Month'])."-".htmlentities ($row_AvDates['the_days']);?></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why did I get a minus?

Answer (score 1):

you can have the whole output in one single like this

```
<?php echo htmlentities($row_AvDates['Month']) . '-' . htmlentities($row_AvDates['the_days']);?>
```

instead of separate php tags

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate code across multiple lines, not all code in one line:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($AvDates) > 0){
?>
<ul>
<?php

    while ($row_AvDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($AvDates)){ 
 ?>


        <li><?php 
            echo htmlentities($row_AvDates['Month']);
            echo "-";
            echo htmlentities($row_AvDates['the_days']);
        ?></li> 
<?php
    }      
?>
</ul>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: i think he/she wants to loose the tabs instead of introducing them